# Checking inventory, if exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if the the productID exist in the database and don't allow to update if the the productID does not exist

This is the code I used for checking

```
 bool HasInventory()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvMaterialsList.Items)
    {

        Label ltr = (Label)item.FindControl("Label1");

        string name = ltr.Text;
        bool existing = true;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProductID FROM Inventory WHERE ProductID=" + name;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", name);
        SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (data.HasRows)
            existing = true;
        else
            existing = false;
        con.Close();

        return existing;

    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the code for the button used to update the database

```
 protected void lvMaterialsList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    bool existingSupply = IsExisting();
    bool hasquantity = HasInventory();

    Label ltRefNo = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ltRefNo");
    Label Label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
    TextBox txtAlloted = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtAlloted");
    Literal ltUsed = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltUsed");

    int alloted = Convert.ToInt32(txtAlloted.Text);
    int productid = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);

    if (e.CommandName == "updateused")
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        if (existingSupply && hasquantity)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE RequiredMaterials SET Used=Used + @Used WHERE ReqMatID=@ReqMatID";

        }
       else 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE RequiredMaterials SET Used=@Used WHERE ReqMatID=@ReqMatID";
        }

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Used", alloted);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqMatID", ltRefNo.Text);                      
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity " +
            "WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", alloted);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", productid);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


    }

    GetMaterialsList();

}
```

I don't know why it keeps on updating..

Comment: What you mean by saying 'keeps on updating'? When you have no product ID in Inventory table then simply it will not update any rows.

Comment: @MIdrees. I mean it is keeps updating on inputting I am working with 2 tables. I must not input

Comment: From the code, it seems you declared the "bool hasquantity = HasInventory();" but I did not see any IF check in the code ? Or might be there is some other code for input?

Comment: What do you mean that the is no IF check in the code

Comment: "I want to check if the the productID exist in the database and don't allow to update if the the productID does not exist"...from this it seems some where you write the IF check.

Comment: I don't think I have wrote an IF check, the only If statement that I used is in the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91301/discussion-between-m-idrees-and-gamered123).